# htaccess https/http redirect issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to use redirect links using HTACCESS for http and https.

This is my HTACCESS code:

```
RewriteRule ^go/(https:\/*)*(.+)$ https://$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^go/(http:\/*)*(.+)$ http://$2 [L,R=301]
```

When I'm using https links it works fine:

```
http://mywebsite.com/go/https://facebook.com
```

leads to `https://facebook.com`

But for some reason when I use http it reads it like https and this is what happens:
`http://website.com/go/http://facebook.com` leads to `https://http/facebook.com`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in Advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure why you would want to link to external sites as fake links on your own, but ok..

you could probably condense those to 1 rule like:

> RewriteRule ^go/(http(s?):/{1,2})(.+)$ http$2://$3 [R=301,L]

Comment: Usually when external links are implemented using redirects it's so that the traffic can be tracked as it leaves the site.